# How to use item metadata as argument to an item function in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

Assume I have the following items

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Foo Include="a1">
    <Key>a</Key>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="a2">
    <Key>a</Key>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="b1">
    <Key>b</Key>
  </Foo>
  <Bar Include="bar1">
    <UseKey>a</UseKey>
  </Bar>
  <Bar Include="bar2">
    <UseKey>b</UseKey>
  </Bar>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now I want to set a new piece of metadata called `Foos` on `Bar` items. `Foos` contains all Foo items that have a matched `Key`. For example, with the above items I want Bars to become

```xml
  <Bar Include="bar1">
    <UseKey>a</UseKey>
    <Foos>a1;a2</Foos>
  </Bar>
  <Bar Include="bar2">
    <UseKey>b</UseKey>
    <Foos>b1</Foos>
  </Bar>
```

I tried something like the following but it does not work.

```xml
<Target>
  <Bar>
    <Foos>@(Foo->WithMetadataValue('Key', '%(Bar.UseKey)'))</Foos>
  </Bar>
</Target>
```

Replacing `%(Bar.UseKey)` with the actual key value like `a` or `b` does filter Foos as expected, but instead of filtering by a fixed value, I want to filter by the `UseKey` metadata on Bars. Can this be achieved with msbuild or do I need a custom task to do this?